# How to place a gradient layer onto a UIImageView that has no frame

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, gradient

I am trying to place a gray transparent gradient over an image in my ios app, but it doesn't work because of issues with the frame. Since my `UIImageView` is set up programmatically and with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, the gradient layer is not visible when I set it's frame to the image frame. I don't want to set the either frame to a constant because the image is in a collection view cell that uses the `sizeForItemAt` function to determine the size of each of my cells and so the size of the image changes with the size of the cell and I need my gradient to have the same size as the image.

I have tried to setup the gradient by creating a `UIView` that I place as the subview of the `UIImageView` but had no luck with that due to issues with the frame again. I have seen other posts about adding gradient layers but they all require me to define a frame for the gradient.

```swift
//This is the imageview and the gradient that I want to apply to it
let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    } ()
var gradient: CAGradientLayer = {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor,    UIColor.gray.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.opacity = 0.7
        return gradientLayer
    }()

//This is the setupviews() function where I apply the gradient to the imageview
func setupViews() {
        self.contentView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        profileImageView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

        //constraints for profileImageView
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[v0]-0-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": profileImageView]))

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[v0]-0-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": profileImageView]))
}
```

Currently in order for the gradient to show up, I would need to define a frame for the gradient layer in `setupViews()`, but as I described before I would prefer to not do that. Is there a way to create a gradient layer without defining a specific frame, or is there another better way to apply the gradient layer in my case? Thanks!

EDIT: I would like to clarify that all of the views in my `UICollectionViewCell` class do not have frames. They are all setup with constraints programmatically, so if I tried to print `view.frame.height` or `view.frame.width` the program would print zero despite the actual height and width of the view not being zero. Therefore, defining any sort of frame for a gradient or setting the frame of the gradient to the frame of the view will not work. Would I have to restructure the way my views are set up in order to be able to place a gradient over an image? Or can I still hope for salvation from this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can :
- Create a Swift file with the below code
- Set you imageView to this class
- Put this imageView or UIView (in that case turn the class accordingly) above the UIImageView that contains your image.
And it should work (see example screenshots).
Modify parameters as you wish with your colors / alpha setting.
Hope it will help.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AddGradientsToImageView: UIImageView {

// For item created programmatically
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addGradientsToImageView()
}

// For items created in the storyboard
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    addGradientsToImageView()
}

func addGradientsToImageView() {

// Set background gradient colors
let lightBlue = UIColor(red: 112/255, green: 117/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1)
let darkBlue = UIColor(red: 70/255, green: 84/255, blue: 201/255, alpha: 1)

// Set gradients
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = bounds
gradientLayer.colors = [darkBlue.cgColor, lightBlue.cgColor]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0,1.0]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

// Clip gradients to background bounds
clipsToBounds = true

// Set transparency level
alpha = 0.50

// insert gradients to button
layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
}
```

[result of the code to this imageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW8FC.png)
[result of the code with a picture behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCESb.png)

Comment: I assume this would require me to define a frame for the gradient?

Comment: Yes you may need to keep a frame, but may not need to specifiy any size to the gradient layer; have you tried to clipsToBounds your gradient? Well, that what I am getting with the above whatever the szie of the picture is.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom class that inherits from UIImageView, add the layer when you create it, and override layoutsubviews()

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
   customlayer.frame = self.bounds     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will try to access the UIImageView in `sizeForItem`, then you will resize the gradient sublayer in that method?